# Why can call a method that the superclass does not have

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiple-inheritance, superclass, method-resolution-order

I'm reading the source code implemting the paxos algorithm with Python 2.7. In the code, there are lots of methods which call the methods of superclass that there exactly isn't this method in the superclass and the names of these two methods are always the same. Is this a special feature for Python?
eg. super(SimpleSynchronizationStrategyMixin,self).set_messenger(messenger)
the superclass of SimpleSynchronizationStrategyMixin is object not containing the method "set_messenger". exactly the name of method, which this line of  code belongs to, is also "set_messenger"

```py
class SimpleSynchronizationStrategyMixin(object):

    sync_delay = 10.0

    def set_messenger(self, messenger):
        super(SimpleSynchronizationStrategyMixin,self).set_messenger(messenger)

        def sync():
            self.messenger.send_sync_request(random.choice(self.peers), self.instance_number)

        self.sync_task = task.LoopingCall(sync)
        self.sync_task.start(self.sync_delay)


    def receive_sync_request(self, from_uid, instance_number):
        if instance_number < self.instance_number:
            self.messenger.send_catchup(from_uid, self.instance_number, self.current_value)


    def receive_catchup(self, from_uid, instance_number, current_value):
        if instance_number > self.instance_number:
            print 'SYNCHRONIZED: ', instance_number, current_value
            self.advance_instance(instance_number, current_value, catchup=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted seems strange indeed, and using this class on its own would indeed fail. For example, using the following minimal example:

```py
class SimpleSynchronizationStrategyMixin(object):

    def set_messenger(self, messenger):
        super(SimpleSynchronizationStrategyMixin,self).set_messenger(messenger)
        print('test')


test = SimpleSynchronizationStrategyMixin()
test.set_messenger(None)
```

would give an error, as you would have expected:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'set_messenger'
```

However, the name of the class reveals the answer: it is a "mixin" class, a class that is intended to be *mixed in with another class*. So the class only adds certain functionality, and may make assumptions about methods being present in the super object (which is **not** `object` in the case of the final object).

To demonstrate this, let's extend the above example with the following code:

```py
class SomeOtherClass(object):

    def set_messenger(self, messenger):
        print('setting the messenger to %s.' % repr(messenger))


class Demo(SimpleSynchronizationStrategyMixin, SomeOtherClass):

    def demo(self):
        self.set_messenger('some messenger')


demo = Demo()
demo.demo()
```

Here, the `set_messenger` method is defined in `SomeOtherClass`. The `Demo` class then uses the `SomeOtherClass` with the mixin to create the final object. When `demo()` is called, it prints:

```
setting the messenger to 'some messenger'.
test
```

Note that the order of the super classes is important. If you would write `class Demo(SomeOtherClass, SimpleSynchronizationStrategyMixin)` then the line "test" would not be printed.

For your specific paxos example, see `server.py`, which contains:

```py
class ReplicatedValue(DedicatedMasterStrategyMixin, ExponentialBackoffResolutionStrategyMixin, SimpleSynchronizationStrategyMixin, BaseReplicatedValue):
    """
    Mixes the dedicated master, resolution, and synchronization strategies into the base class
    ""
```

Here you can see that a number of mixin classes are "added" to `BaseReplicatedValue` to create `ReplicatedValue`.

Note that `super()` does not always return the "parent" object. If the method `DedicatedMasterStrategyMixin.propose_update(self, ...)` calls `super(DedicatedMasterStrategyMixin, self).propose_update(...)`, it finds the next `propose_update()` method according to the [Method Resolution Order (MRO)](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). Simply said, it looks in all base classes from left to right, and returns the first method found. In this way, each method can call `super()` without knowing which class is the "parent", so that still all necessary methods can be chained. The following example code demonstrates this:

```py
class Base(object):
    def test(self):
        # NB: No super() call in the base class!
        print('Test Base')
        print('')

class MixinX(object):
    def test(self):
        print('Test X')
        super(MixinX, self).test()

class MixinY(object):
    def test(self):
        print('Test Y')
        super(MixinY, self).test()

class MixinZ(object):
    def test(self):
        print('Test Z')
        super(MixinZ, self).test()

class Final(Base):
    pass

class FinalX(MixinX, Base):
    pass

class FinalXYZ(MixinX, MixinY, MixinZ, Base):
    pass

class FinalZYX(MixinZ, MixinY, MixinX, Base):
    pass

class WrongOrder(Base, MixinX, MixinY, MixinZ):
    pass

class MixinsOnly(MixinX, MixinY, MixinZ):
    pass


"""
>>> Final().test()
Test Base

>>> FinalX().test()
Test X
Test Base

>>> FinalXYZ().test()
Test X
Test Y
Test Z
Test Base

>>> FinalZYX.test()
Test Z
Test Y
Test X
Test Base

>>> WrongOrder().test()
Test Base

>>> MixinsOnly().test()
Test X
Test Y
Test Z
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "superdemo.py", line 36, in <module>
    MixinsOnly().test()
  File "superdemo.py", line 9, in test
    super(MixinX, self).test()
  File "superdemo.py", line 14, in test
    super(MixinY, self).test()
  File "superdemo.py", line 19, in test
    super(MixinZ, self).test()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'test'

>>> FinalXYZ.mro()
[<class '__main__.FinalXYZ'>, <class '__main__.MixinX'>, <class '__main__.MixinY'>, <class '__main__.MixinZ'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <type 'object'>]
"""
```

Comment: thanks.But there is still a question."A number of mixin classes are "added" to BaseReplicatedValue to create ReplicatedValue" dostn't influnce the superclass of `DedicatedMasterStrategyMixin`.   `r = ReplicatedValue()` `r.propose_update()` Here r will call the `propose_update` in `DedicatedMasterStrategyMixin` .And `propose_update` in `DedicatedMasterStrategyMixin` has this code `super(DedicatedMasterStrategyMixin,self).propose_update( json.dumps( [None,new_value] ) )` which means that finally r call the `propse_update` in superclass of `DedicatedMasterStrategyMixin`, which excatly is `object`

Comment: @asuka, I understand the confusion. I've updated my answer with some additional information and hope this answers your question. Check the included link about MRO for more detailed information about how this works.

Comment: PS: I assume the mentioned code is (something like) [this github project](https://github.com/cocagne/multi-paxos-example), for anyone interested in the full code.

Comment: @asukua, I added some example code demonstrating how the MRO works. I hope this helps! Please mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question, otherwise let me know how the answer could be improved :-)